# How much does server space cost?

Tags: web-services, hosting, shared-hosting

I want to hst a 'send link to my phone feature' on my website. Can someone with server experience suggest to me which company I should go with based on my needs?

More info: I'll be using host gator to host my domain and its pages. I want this text me feature to be on the homepage and it could possibly send millions of links over the coming years (think positive right?) What should I do? I heard this type of feature costs money and I am doing budgeting now.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to do. If you want an SMS gateway to send links to peoples' mobiles, then Txtlocal is a good option but they charge about 2p a per message I think

Comment: Idk what to call it, i've just been calling it 'send link to phone'. whats it actually called? i need to be able to research efficiently